# MQ Connection pooling gives error "This session is closed."

Tags: activemq-classic, ibm-mq

I have a standalone java client program that sends messages to a queue on websphere mq system. I want to avoid the creation of new connection, session and producer for every message so I use the connection pooling facilities that are provided by activemq-jms-pool package (v5.11.1).

The setup of this connection pool is as follows:

```
        this.fConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory();
        ((PooledConnectionFactory)this.fConnectionFactory).setConnectionFactory(mqConnectionFactory);
((PooledConnectionFactory)this.fConnectionFactory).setMaxConnections(1);
            ((PooledConnectionFactory)this.fConnectionFactory).setMaximumActiveSessionPerConnection(1);
            ((PooledConnectionFactory)this.fConnectionFactory).setExpiryTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000);
            ((PooledConnectionFactory)this.fConnectionFactory).setIdleTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000);
            ((PooledConnectionFactory)this.fConnectionFactory).setReconnectOnException(true);
            ((PooledConnectionFactory)this.fConnectionFactory).setCreateConnectionOnStartup(true);
```

My MQ client itself is version "7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424". Websphere MQ itself is version 8.

However from time to time I see the following exception in my logs:

```
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.ConfigEnvironment$1: MQJMS2007: failed to send message to MQ queue.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.ConfigEnvironment.newException(ConfigEnvironment.java:379) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageProducer.sendInternal(MQMessageProducer.java:1218) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:2490) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:2608) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendMessage(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:927) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.send_(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:783) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.send(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:363) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:274) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:95) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.11.1.jar:5.11.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:71) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.11.1.jar:5.11.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2009'.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.base.internal.MQQueueManager.putMsg2(MQQueueManager.java:617) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageProducer.sendInternal(MQMessageProducer.java:1178) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    ... 34 common frames omitted


08:37:05.989 [main] WARN  o.a.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession - Caught exception trying close() when putting session back into the pool, will invalidate. com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC0020: This session is closed.
An application called a method that must not be used after the session is closed.
Ensure that the session is not closed before calling the method.
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC0020: This session is closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.8 - p750-008-170628]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:233) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.8 - p750-008-170628]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:109) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.State.checkNotClosed(State.java:150) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.checkNotClosed(JmsSessionImpl.java:2526) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.setMessageListener(JmsSessionImpl.java:1730) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.setMessageListener(MQSession.java:1004) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.close(PooledSession.java:103) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.11.1.jar:5.11.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
```

What is causing this error (and how can it be avoided) ? 
There are no network issues and there is also no firewall in between. The issue seems to occur when there is some time between the sending of different messages (like 5 minutes or so).

Thx for the assistance.

EDIT 06/12/2018: Added other exception

```
20181204 164448.873 [INFO ] b.g.s.c.j.s.CachingConnectionFactory - Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:585) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.consumer(WMQConnection.java:785) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn.callEventHandler(RemoteHconn.java:2621) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn.driveEventsEH(RemoteHconn.java:601) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.processHconn(RemoteDispatchThread.java:668) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.run(RemoteDispatchThread.java:244) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:214) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:105) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:229) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:303) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1241) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
20181204 164448.873 [TRACE] b.g.s.c.j.s.CachingConnectionFactory - Reset connection, first close cached sessions (active: false).
20181204 164448.874 [TRACE] b.g.s.c.j.s.CachingConnectionFactory - Invoking method close via proxied session handler.
20181204 164448.874 [DEBUG] b.g.s.c.j.s.CachingConnectionFactory - Physically closing cached Session: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession@4bb27555
20181204 164448.874 [TRACE] b.g.s.c.j.s.CachingConnectionFactory - Closing producer com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSender@1aad157c
20181204 164448.878 [TRACE] b.g.s.c.j.s.CachingConnectionFactory - Could not close cached JMS Session
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0019: Failed to disconnect from queue manager 'xx' using connection mode '1' and host name 'xxx(1446)'.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:585) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.disconnect(WMQSession.java:712) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.close(WMQSession.java:663) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:513) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:303) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.close(MQSession.java:298) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at xxx.server.comm.jms.spring.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedSessionInvocationHandler.physicalClose(CachingConnectionFactory.java:567) ~[xxx.server.comm.jms_18.63.7.SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at xxx.server.comm.jms.spring.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:356) ~[xxx.server.comm.jms_18.63.7.SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.close(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.server.comm.jms.spring.CachingConnectionFactory.resetConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:200) ~[xxx.server.comm.jms_18.63.7.SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at xxx.server.comm.jms.spring.SingleConnectionFactory.onException(SingleConnectionFactory.java:387) [xxx.server.comm.jms_18.63.7.SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at xxx.server.comm.jms.spring.SingleConnectionFactory$AggregatedExceptionListener.onException(SingleConnectionFactory.java:832) [xxx.server.comm.jms_18.63.7.SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsProviderExceptionListener.run(JmsProviderExceptionListener.java:427) [com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:214) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:105) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:229) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:303) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1241) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.getConnection(RemoteSession.java:509) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.allocateMQAPI(RemoteSession.java:1375) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.allocateMQAPI(RemoteSession.java:1345) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.MQDISC(RemoteFAP.java:2741) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.MQDISC(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:335) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.MQDISC(ESEJMQI.java:237) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.disconnect(WMQSession.java:693) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host 'xxx/xxx (xxx)'. [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3=xxx/ (xxx),4=TCP]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.receiveBuffer(RemoteRcvThread.java:821) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.receiveOneTSH(RemoteRcvThread.java:757) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:150) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
20181204 164448.878 [DEBUG] b.g.s.c.j.s.CachingConnectionFactory - Closing shared JMS Connection: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection@3bbfe008
20181204 164448.879 [DEBUG] b.g.s.c.j.s.CachingConnectionFactory - Could not close shared JMS Connection
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0019: Failed to disconnect from queue manager 'TM01' using connection mode '1' and host name 'xxx'.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:585) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.close(WMQConnection.java:709) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.close(JmsConnectionImpl.java:347) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.close(MQConnection.java:98) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at xxx.server.comm.jms.spring.SingleConnectionFactory.closeConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:546) [xxx.server.comm.jms_18.63.7.SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at xxx.server.comm.jms.spring.SingleConnectionFactory.resetConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:413) [xxx.server.comm.jms_18.63.7.SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at xxx.server.comm.jms.spring.CachingConnectionFactory.resetConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:213) [xxx.server.comm.jms_18.63.7.SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at xxx.server.comm.jms.spring.SingleConnectionFactory.onException(SingleConnectionFactory.java:387) [xxx.server.comm.jms_18.63.7.SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at xxx.server.comm.jms.spring.SingleConnectionFactory$AggregatedExceptionListener.onException(SingleConnectionFactory.java:832) [xxx.server.comm.jms_18.63.7.SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsProviderExceptionListener.run(JmsProviderExceptionListener.java:427) [com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:214) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:105) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:229) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:303) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1241) [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.getConnection(RemoteSession.java:509) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.allocateMQAPI(RemoteSession.java:1375) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.allocateMQAPI(RemoteSession.java:1345) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.MQDISC(RemoteFAP.java:2741) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.MQDISC(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:335) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.MQDISC(ESEJMQI.java:237) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.close(WMQConnection.java:692) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host 'xxx'. [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3=xxx,4=TCP]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.receiveBuffer(RemoteRcvThread.java:821) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.receiveOneTSH(RemoteRcvThread.java:757) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:150) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.7 - p750-007-160812]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What is SHARECNV set to on the SVRCONN channel?   I find it strange that the 7505 jar files produce errors that state wmq.v6.jms unless SHARECNV is 0.  What error is in the MQ queue manager logs when the java client gets the 2009?

Comment: Seems that this parameter is set to 0. Guess this can explain the issue if I read the meaning of this parameter in the docs ?

Comment: shareconv of 0 just means that each connection is on a dedicated TCP/IP connection. It will not prevent 2009 exceptions

Comment: `SHARECNV(0)` turns off new channel features introduced in v7 and causes the channel to work in a v6 and earlier mode.  It ALSO as @newbie mentioned causes each JMS connect and session to be on a dedicated TCP/IP connection.  You can set this to `SHARECNV(1)` and have the channel features introduced in v7 while still having each JMS connect and session to be on a dedicated TCP/IP connection.  One feature added is that heart beat messages are bidirectional where before this they flowed from the server only when the client issues an MQGET call with wait.

Comment: What is the value of `HBINT` on the SVRCONN channel?

Comment: It was the Asynchronous Consume that was turned off

Comment: @newbie it is also bidirectional heart beat that is turned off.  See [IBM MQ 8.0.0>IBM MQ>Configuring>Configuring distributed queuing>Introduction to distributed queue management>Channel control function>Checking that the other end of the channel is still available](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q015650_.htm),  "Provided SHARECNV is not zero, the client uses a full duplex connection, which means that the client can (and does) heartbeat during all MQI calls".

Comment: HBINT is 30 for the channel. I have requested our MQ admins to set the value of SHARECNV to 5 iso 0. Once done I can retest but I also highly suspect that this value has something to do with it due to the missing heartbeats.

Comment: I would recommend `SHARECNV(1)` for performance reasons.  With HBINT(30) the ReceiveTimeout is set 60 seconds.   Do you see the 2009 if you do not send a message for 60 seconds?  In any case I think you will find that setting `SHARECNV` to 1 or larger will resolve your 2009 issue.  Once you confirm it fixes it I'll write up a answer and put all the comment information into it with better formatting and links to the documentation.

Comment: Can you ask the MQ admins if when you receive the 2009 they see a TIMEOUT 60 error in the queue managers AMQERR01.LOG?

Comment: @JoshMc: setting the SHARECNV to a value > 0 did resolve the 2009 issue above. However we now have another type of 2009 error: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host 'xxx'. [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3=xxx,4=TCP]. Mq admins don't have AMQERR01.LOG apparently since it is MQ on z/OS

Comment: The error indicates you did not receive a response from the server in the receive timeout or the connection broke, the receive timeout for `HBINT(30)` would be `60` seconds.   Does this channel use TLS or is there something that would cause the java process to block and not send HB to the queue manager (ex: garbage collection, debug break points)?  The z/OS team should have access to an equivalent z/OS MQ log (console log for instance) that can show what the queue manager things happened to the connection.

Comment: Double check the version of the MQ jar files are from a consistent version of MQ.  Note in your stack trace I see two versions: `[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.8 - p750-008-170628]` and `[com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.5.jar:7.5.0.5 - p750-005-150424]`, all `com.ibm.mq*.jar` files should be from the same version of the MQ client.  Note also that MQ v7.5 went out of support on April 30 2018, you would be better going with a later version 8.0, 9.0, or 9.1, these all can be deployed with a single jar file `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` along with the JMS 2.0 `jms.jar`.

Comment: @JoshMc: I have added the complete new exception. For the moment however this exception is not occurring anymore. Not sure why (channel restart/server restart ? ). The channel was indeed using TLS. Version mix-up is probably due to local testing with different versions. Normally it should be 7.5.0.7 that we use.

Comment: Some times the TLS can cause timeouts but those normally occur during the initial channel startup, not after it has been running, is this new 2009 happen at startup or after the channel is running for awhile?  Seeing the equivalent z/OS MQ system error should help to narrow the cause, but as you said it is working now.  If it was TLS then it is possible the z/OS team could have corrected a config that was previously causing the timeout.

Comment: Didn't have the impression it was linked to startup of the  channel, happened more when it was running. I will keep monitoring my logs and make another post when it occurs again and ask the MQ system logs. You definitely helped me to resolve the "Session closed" issue by pointing me in the direction of the SHARECNV parameter, thanks a lot for that !

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is the following linked exception

MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2009'.

What this means is that the underlying TCP/IP connection has been closed underneath the messsaging client/server. Typically this issue occurs when there is a lack of activity which causes a firewall to close the connection.

To resolve just change the firewall rule that is causing the connection to be closed.

Comment: Hello, there is no firewall between the client and the server.

Comment: well then it's the TCP/IP operating settings (KEEPALIVE) that is the next suspect.

Comment: Or you have some TCP/IP transport hardware that is closing inactive connections. Please be aware that closing TCP/IP connections at the transport level is not an error , it's considered good behaviour